# Unit Test Linq XML Function

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing

I have the next function which creates a List from the data in the document.

I need to do some unit testing but have no clue how to actually do that for this particular function. I have read everywhere but still no luck.

```
public List<Info> getInfo()
{
    XDocument doc = loadDocument();

    var variable = (from elem in doc.Descendants("Information").Elements()
                   select new Info
                   {
                       Include = elem.Element("Include") != null && (elem.Element("Include").Value.Equals("true") || elem.Element("Include").Value.Equals("false")) ? Convert.ToBoolean(elem.Element("Include").Value) : false,
                       InfoName = elem.Element("Name") != null ? elem.Element("Name").Value : String.Empty,
                       StartDate = elem.Element("StartDate") != null ? elem.Element("StartDate").Value : String.Empty,
                       EndDate = elem.Element("EndDate") != null ? elem.Element("EndDate").Value : String.Empty,
                       Mark = elem.Element("Mark") != null ? Convert.ToDouble(elem.Element("Mark").Value) : Double.NaN
                   }
                   ).ToList();

    return variable;
}

public XDocument loadDocument() 
{ 
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("info.xml"); 
    return doc; 
}
```

Comment: How much about unit tests do you know? What does `loadDocument()` do? Do you know how to mock inputs and dependencies and how are you doing that in your system?

Comment: public XDocument loadDocument()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("info.xml");
            return doc;
        }
This is what load document does. I have looked over some examples but I am mainly new to unit testing and hit this roadblock.

Comment: @EmilPopescu try to avoid putting code in comments. [edit] your question with the relevant information to make it a [mcve]

Comment: Who told you to "do some unit testing"? Maybe they have some helpful pointers for you. Usually you test units of *your* code to ensure they do what you think they do. Until proven otherwise, assume that provided library code like LINQ and LINQ to XML works as it should. Your test looks like you're double-checking built in functionality. That's usually not very helpful. At most, you're checking that `info.xml` has the structure, you expect. If that is, what you want to check:  great.

Comment: @Corak there is not test yet. The code provided so far looks like the subject under test.

Comment: Oh, I see. Okay, what you can check for example is, what should happen if there is no `info.xml`? What if it's not a valid xml? What if it doesn't have the structure you expect... things like that. Basically: think of everything that could go wrong and see if your code reacts as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is create a unit test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckMyData()
{
    var _info = GenerateData();
    Assert.IsTrue(_info.Include == true); //Mock condition to fulfill.
    Assert.IsFalse(_info.InfoName.Contains("test1_Name"));
    //... and so on...
    //You can also check for the expected type of values.
}

private Info GenerateData()
{
    var data = new Info
        {
          //We set some mokup values here
          Include = true,
          InfoName = "test_NAME",
          StartDate = "12-12-2005",
          EndDate = "14/12/2005",
          Mark = 12
        }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Ffakinglinqqueries.htm) is exactly what you need.
This mocking framework has the unique ability to mock LinQ functions.
You can also send your code sample to their support and they will guide you how to do that correctly